# Bootstrap Password section broken on click

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

**EDIT: I had a good look for the problem, and this has something to do with it, not sure why but in the text input, it is removing the rounding off the password input when not highlighted, if I remove the lines, then it all gets rounded:**

```
.login .form-signin input[type="text"] {
  margin-bottom: -1px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
}
.login .form-signin input[type="password"] {
  border-top-left-radius: 0;
  border-top-right-radius: 0;
}
```

Sorry didn't know how to best word the topic, but I have this issue, where the rounding of the password field is in the wrong places for no reason and when you click in the password field it moves the sign in button down and the rounding goes in the correct bottom 2 corners. As far as I know, the HTML and CSS is pretty much identical to the bootstrap one.

here is an image before and after

before:

[image: before]

after:

[image: after]

you can see the difference in space between the bottom of the password field to the sign in field, and the rounding is broken. Also this only happens in browsers that dont support webkit such as IE8 or IE9. I know for a fact it should work because it does in other login forms like the example one on bootstrap's website.

Thanks
- Dan

Comment: Would help to show your html and css

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to answer without knowing what your css and html looks like, but it seems like a class is being added to the password input when you focus on it.

If using chrome: inspect the element on the password field, right click on the element in the dev tools and select 'force element state' > ':focus'. 
If there are different attributes you should be able to tell by comparing the forced state with the normal state

Comment: I edited it just now with CSS that I think is causing the problem